# bootstrap dose not effect on django templates

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am new to bootstrap( v 3.1.1)  and i want to use it with my django project.
I include all needed css an js file as said in (http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book/chapters/bootstrap.html)  and I can access bootstrap css file from my project static url from web browser  ( I mean correct configuration of setting file)

but when I use bootstrap componenst in my templates it dose not work .for example when add bootstrap class for button nothing changed

here is my base.html file which other tmeplates inhirent from base.html template

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta  name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`    
<link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css'% }" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap-them.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">   
<title> {% block title %} dance with Django {% endblock %}</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="btn-group dropup">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Dropup</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
<span class="caret"></span>
<span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
</button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<!-- Dropdown menu links -->
</ul>
</div>
{% block body_block %}
{% endblock %}
<script src="{% static 'js/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

also here is my setting.py

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'rango',
)
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',)
 ROOT_URLCONF = 'tango_with_django_project.urls'
 WSGI_APPLICATION = 'tango_with_django_project.wsgi.application'
 DATABASES = {
'default': {'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'rango.db'),
}
}

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = ( os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),)
STATICFILES_DIRS = ( os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),)
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',   )
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',)


 TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS=(
 "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
 'django.core.context_processors.request',
 "django.core.context_processors.debug",
 "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
 "django.core.context_processors.media",
 "django.core.context_processors.static",
 "django.core.context_processors.tz",
 "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages")
```

Comment: i think you have typo in your file name - bootstrap-them.min.css.. .shouldnt it be bootstrap-theme.min.css ?

Comment: So yea, basically, make sure your template files are not getting 404 errors. Cause from what i can see in your html, all the relevant classes should be in use.

Comment: I also correct my typo error . I checked with firebug and I am getting 404 errors with my bootstrap.css . here is my setting static variable configs: STATIC_URL = '/static/'   STATICFILES_DIRS = ( os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),)

Comment: Are you using the built in development web server? If not, did you run collectstatic?

Comment: There are more typos when loading scripts, ' %} is missing.

Comment: I'm using development server . and thank your for typo corrections :D . instead of <link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap-theme.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">    I use <link href="{{STATIC_URL}}'css/bootstrap-theme.css'" rel="stylesheet"> and every think is ok .

Comment: it seems that {% static ......%} dose not work

Answer (score 0):

To enable templatetag {% static %} you first have to load static files like this:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
```

Read more on this here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/

Comment: I also add {% load staticfiles %} tag but still it dose not work